# Can an Ansible filter return Undefined?

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-filter

I'm writing an Ansible filter. Is it possible that this filter returns `Undefined`, so that the resulting output is `Undefined`?

My goal is that I can use the filter in conjunction with `default` or `select` in situations like:

```
my_variable: "{{ my_input | myfilter | default(something) }}"
```

or:

```
my_list: "{{ list_of_things | map('myfilter') | select | list }}"
```

For example:

```
- vars:
    area: 9
    side: "{{ area | my_sqrt | default(0) }}"
  debug:
    var: side
```

or:

```
- vars:
    numbers: [16, 9, -4]
    roots: "{{ numbers | map('my_sqrt') | select | list }}"
  debug:
    var: roots
```

where `map('my_sqrt')` should output `[4, 3, Undefined]` and `select` should turn that into `[4, 3]`.

I tried to defined `my_sqrt` as:

```
import math
from jinja2.runtime import Undefined

def my_sqrt(input):
    if input < 0:
        return Undefined
    else:
        return math.sqrt(input)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return { 'my_sqrt': my_sqrt }
```

However, when I execute the above playbook, it seem to return the string `<class 'jinja2.runtime.Undefined'>`.

A bit of further testing proves this:

`('never' if 0) | default('the_default')` indeed returns `the_default`.

However, `-4 | my_sqrt | default('the_default')` sadly returns the string `"<class 'jinja2.runtime.Undefined'>"`.

I've both tried with `jinja2.runtime.Undefined` and `ansible.template.AnsibleUndefined`.

I'm primarily interested to hear if an Ansible/Jinja2 filter can return `Undefined`.

If that's not possible, I'm interested to hear alternative approaches. What I'm actually am writing is a filter that takes an object and a list of options (possible matches), and will return the best option (best match). If there is no good option, it should return `Undefined`, after which it is up to the playbook to deal with the situation. As a basic requirement, it should work will with both `default` and `select`.

Comment: One workaround that works with `default` is to return an empty value, and use `default(something, true)`. However, I haven't been able to get that to work with `select`. I'm happy to accept an answer that explain how to make with work with both `default` and `select`.

Comment: Why is returning the easier-to-reason-about `None` not an option for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define your `filter` to return `None` instead of `Undefined`. Then you could pipe the output to both the `select` and `default` filter, with a caveat.

`None` will be interpreted by the `default` filter as a boolean value. So, you must pass the value `true` as the second parameter of the `default` filter for it to work as expected.

Try it using this code:

**Filter Definition:**

```py
#!/bin/bash

import math
import typing as t

V = t.TypeVar("V")

def my_sqrt(value: V) -> t.Union[V , None]:
    if value < 0:
        return None
    else:
        return math.sqrt(value)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'my_sqrt': my_sqrt
        }
```

**Playbook example:**

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Test the my_sqrt filter
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item | my_sqrt | default(0, true) }}"
      loop:
        - 4
        - -1

    - name: Select
      debug:
        msg: "{{ [4, 3, -4] | map('my_sqrt') | select | list }}"
```

You'll see that both `tasks` work as expected:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************
Friday 14 May 2021  09:27:41 -0300 (0:00:00.019)       0:00:00.019 ************ 

TASK [Test the my_sqrt filter] *************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) => 
  msg: '2.0'
ok: [localhost] => (item=-1) => 
  msg: '0'
Friday 14 May 2021  09:27:41 -0300 (0:00:00.042)       0:00:00.062 ************ 

TASK [Select] ******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg:
  - 2.0
  - 1.7320508075688772

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   

Friday 14 May 2021  09:27:41 -0300 (0:00:00.044)       0:00:00.106 ************ 
=============================================================================== 
Select ------------------------------------------------------------------ 0.04s
Test the my_sqrt filter ------------------------------------------------- 0.04s
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be impossible under the default settings ([non-Jinja native](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-jinja2-native)), as Ansible [tries very hard](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/6c21c545e169f5d68a2c10d285ce3489b28dde2c/lib/ansible/template/native_helpers.py#L31) to smash your return values to a string type. (At least I couldn't do it, save for [monkey-patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626193/what-is-monkey-patching) the Ansible core in ways that felt fragile.)

On the other hand, if you either set `ANSIBLE_JINJA2_NATIVE=1` in your wrapper shell script; or have an `ansible.cfg` file that reads

```
[defaults]
jinja_native = true
```

(which I humbly suggest you make a habit of, at least in new projects); then returning a “real” undefined value from a filter or lookup plugin is a piece of cake:

```
from jinja2.runtime import Undefined


class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    def run(self, terms, variables=None, **kwargs):
       return [Undefined("Don't look up")]
```

`| default`, `is defined` etc. will then work as you would expect, and you can customize the error message (through the `Undefined` constructor argument, as shown above) that Ansible will show in case the undefined value propagates to the top level.